# Trying to create a webhook using Google Cloud Platform and receiving "Service Unavailable" when testing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, webhooks

I am trying to build a webhook interface using Cloud Functions in Google Cloud Patform. I am able to deploy the function, but receive a "Service not available" when testing in the Cloud Shell:

```
curl -m 70 -X POST https://us-central1-webhookattentive.cloudfunctions.net/function-2 \
> -H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" \
> -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
> -d '{}'
Service Unavailable
```

I looked at the log, but did not think there was another instance running which would cause the message "Address already in use":

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8080 at
Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] 
(node:net:1740:16) at listenInCluster (node:net:1788:12) at 
Server.listen (node:net:1876:7) at 
main (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/main.js:45:14)
```

The function itself is nothing fancy:

```
const express = require('express');
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

// Create a new instance of the Storage client
const storage = new Storage();

// Define your Google Cloud Storage bucket name
const bucketName = 'attentivesignup';

app.post('/webhook', async (req, res) => {
  const webhookPayload = req.body;
  
  // Write the webhook payload to a file in Google Cloud Storage
  const filename = `webhook-${Date.now()}.json`;
  const file = storage.bucket(bucketName).file(filename);
  
  await file.save(JSON.stringify(webhookPayload), {
    contentType: 'application/json',
    gzip: true,
  });

  console.log(`Webhook payload saved to: gs://${bucketName}/${filename}`);
  
  // Send a response back to Attentive
  res.status(200).send('Webhook received successfully');
});

// Start the server
app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('Server running on port 8080');
});
exports.webhook = app;
```

I was hoping that this would write the input from the call into a file within GCP. Instead, I got that error.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: The code you are using will work in Google Cloud Run but will not work in Cloud Functions. See @DougStevenson's answer. Given that you are writing a webhook, you might find the development process easier by building a container that you can test locally and deploy to Cloud Run.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I didn't need the `app.listen` (as you pointed out), plus having the `await` was not helpful. I'll need to practice more on writing code for Cloud Functions. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `app.listen` in Cloud Functions. The infrastructure for Cloud Functions HTTP triggers will listen for you.  You have to export the function that receives the request.

I suggest reviewing the documentation on how HTTP triggers work.

If you are using GCP and gcloud to deploy:

- https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/write-http-functions

If you are using Firebase:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?gen=2nd

You can use an express app to handle HTTP requests in Cloud Functions, you just can't use it to listen on a port.